# Is it possible to hide or encrypt the display name after login into the WordPress admin panel?

Tags: wp-admin, email

I am not sure this is the right platform to ask this question. Please help me with the correct platform.

Today, One of my clients asked the below question.

> I have login into the WordPress admin panel using the email id and
> password shared by you. Now what I did, after login right clicks on the
> page and click on inspect element then I search for my email id and I
> found my email id(shared screenshot below). I don't want to show my
> email like this. eighter encrypt my email id or remove it from the
> inspect element. This is a security issue.

[image]

I explained to him that this will only show to the login user not everyone on the website and then the argument started.

I believe that this is the WordPress default functionality. I want to know if is there any way to handle this issue.

Comment: Can't you just change the display name in the profile to something that's not an email address?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I tried that too, instated of email, I have set his name.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the "Howdy" message shown on the admin black bar after login, you can use code similar to this to filter that information.

```
    add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'lets_change_howdy', 11);

function lets_change_howdy($wp_admin_bar) {
    $user_id      = get_current_user_id();
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $profile_url  = get_edit_profile_url($user_id);

    if (0 != $user_id) {
        $avatar = get_avatar($user_id, 28);
        $howdy  = sprintf(__('Welcome, %1$s'), $current_user->display_name);
        $class  = empty($avatar) ? '' : 'with-avatar';

        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
            'id' => 'my-account',
            'parent' => 'top-secondary',
            'title' => $howdy . $avatar,
            'href' => $profile_url,
            'meta' => array(
                'class' => $class,
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

This will change the "Howdy (username)" to "Hello (username)". Adjust as needed for your needs.

It could be that your theme is doing something similar. Search your theme code for that 'admin_bar_menu' filter.

Comment: My client doesn't want the username to be display

Comment: Then change the value of $howdy. You can decide what appears up there. Or set $howdy = "" and nothing will be displayed. Your choice.

Comment: Let me try. Give me sometime

Comment: I have tried adding the code in a function.php  but still getting the <span class='display-name'>test@test.com</span>

Comment: If you use my code exactly as written, the "Howdy, username" will be replaced with "Welcome, username", with an href surrounding it.  I've used this code in several plugins, but adding it to the functions.php file will also enable the change. Although changing the functions.php file is not recommended because the changes will go away when a theme update. Best to use a Child Theme, or create your own plugin. Lots of googles on how to do that.